# Search for a number using multiprocessing.pool in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am looking for a number below 100'000 that fulfills a certain condition `f(x)`.
So far I have written the following code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import itertools
import multiprocessing.pool

paramlist = itertools.product("0123456789", repeat=5)

def function(word):
    number = int(''.join(word))
    # some code

with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=8) as pool:
    pool.imap_unordered(function, paramlist)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Is there a way to improve the efficiency of the code?

Comment: Using `itertools` to produce all numeric strings of a given length, and then converting them to integers, seems unnecessarily complicated - why not just use `range(100000)` as your input?  (This may or may not speed things up significantly, depending on how much work your function is doing with these integers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment posted by jasonharper is "on point." Unless the work done by `function` is sufficiently CPU-intensive, the time saved by running it in parallel will not make up for the additional overhead incurred by creating child processes.

If you are to use multiprocessing, I would simply break up the half-open interval [0, 100_000) into N smaller, non-overlapping half-open intervals where N is the number of CPU processors you have. I have chosen the `f(x)` function (`x ** 2`) such that the value of `x` that satisfies a specific value of `f(x)` (`9801198001`) is skewed so that a serial solution will not find a result (`99001`) until it has checked almost all possible values of `x`. Even so, for such a simple function a multiprocessing solution runs 10 times more slowly than the serial solution.

If the `f(x)` function is monotonically increasing or decreasing, then the serial solution can be further sped up using a  binary search, which I have also included:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def f(x):
    return x ** 2

def search(r):
    for x in r:
        if f(x) == 9801198001:
            return x
    return None

def main():
    import time

    # Parallel processing:
    pool_size = cpu_count()
    interval_size = 100_000 // pool_size
    lower_bound = 0
    args = []
    for _ in range(pool_size - 1):
        args.append(range(lower_bound, lower_bound + interval_size))
        lower_bound += interval_size
    # Final interval:
    args.append(range(lower_bound, 100_000))

    t = time.time()
    with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(search, args):
            if result is not None:
                break
    # An implicit call to pool.terminate() will be called
    # to terminate any remaining submitted tasks
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(f'result = {result}, parallel elapsed time = {elapsed}')

    # Serial processing:
    t = time.time()
    result = search(range(100_000))
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(f'result = {result}, serial elapsed time = {elapsed}')

    # Serial processing using a binary search
    # for monotonically increasing function:
    t = time.time()
    lower = 0
    upper = 100_000
    result = None
    while lower < upper:
        x = lower + (upper - lower) // 2
        sq = f(x)
        if sq == 9801198001:
            result = x
            break
        if sq < 9801198001:
            lower = x + 1
        else:
            upper = x

    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(f'result = {result}, serial binary search elapsed time = {elapsed}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
result = 99001, parallel elapsed time = 0.24248361587524414
result = 99001, serial elapsed time = 0.029256343841552734
result = 99001, serial binary search elapsed time = 0.0
```